# Which web protocols are possible for the url of a CSS background image?

Tags: background-image, network-protocols

I am building an application that requires a `str_replace()` for any strings `http:` or `https:` in the URL of a background-image. Does anyone know of any other protocols that are possible for the URL of a background-image? For example, are any of the following possible, or has anyone seen any of the following in a CSS background-image URL?

```
TCP
UDP
ICMP
POP
FTP
IMAP
```

As one example, is this possible for CSS?

```
#myDiv {    background-image: URL("ftps://mysite.com/pub/myimage.png");    }
```

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: TL;DR: (For at least some of these) Possible: Yes. Probable: No. Should you use/expect them? No.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly legal syntax, following the [CSS standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-uri) by W3C. You may put any legal URI there, but it depends on the browser whether it will work or not.

TCP, UDP and ICMP are a different type of protocols, so they won't work, but ftp, pop and imap can work in theory. See here for syntax: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

You may also replace all the images with [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)s, basically embedding everything.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question.

The [CSS2 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri) doesn't seem to prescribe anything in particular as long as we have [valid URIs as per RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986), nor does [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url).

Whether your URIs will *actually* work then depends on whether your browser can access that URI (and you have the appropriate permissions, etc).

I imagine this is intended, for a reason: it means that **the CSS specification is transport layer agnostic**, which makes plenty of sense.

In practice you can thus, for example, **link to HTTPS resources in a CSS1-compliant stylesheet**, even if CSS1 predates the RFC for [HTTPS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2660).